# How to add an item in an array without removing any item from the list?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array, I want to add a new element at second index in this array, but wihout removing any other item from the list.

```
Current array: 
["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"]
```

After inserting `11` at second place.

```
New Array:
["AA", "11", "BB", "CC", "DD"]
```

This is what i am doing,but its eliminating the last record from the array.

```
   private void inserItem(int pos, String value) {
        String[] result = new String[itemsArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
            result[i] = itemsArray[i];

        result[pos] = value;
        for(int i = pos + 1; i < itemsArray.length; i++)
            result[i] = itemsArray[i-1];

        itemsArray= result;
 }
```

This is the output it gives me; when i use the above method `insertItem(1,"11")`

```
 ["AA", "11", "BB", "CC"]
```

Comment: Change String[] result = new String[itemsArray.length];
to String[] result = new String[itemsArray.length + 1];
... and maybe other places too

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an `ArrayList` ? Simply use the method `ArrayList.add(index, String)`.

Comment: Lets be clear, you cannot change the size of an array after it is created so what you are trying to do will never work. You should just use a LinkedLisy<String> instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the size of an array once created.

You should use a `LinkedList<String>` and its `add(int index, E element)`method:

> public void add(int index, E element) Inserts the specified element at
>   the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at
>   that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds
>   one to their indices).

```
String[] array = {"AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"};
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
list.add(1, "11");
```

Note that you should use a LinkedList, not an ArrayList as the add operation with shifting is more expensive with an ArrayList.

One other thing to consider is that I am only using the array to initially populate the LinkedList. I am not proposing that you should do this every time you want to insert an item. You should stop using the array entirely and just use the LinkedList.

Comment: I like this solution. You might want to show the OP how to get an `String[]` back from the `LinkedList` just in case they really need an array of `String` with the `toArray(T[] a)`.

Comment: your solution handles cases well I suppose. Other solutions, looks like going with "new String[itemsArray.length + 1]", but I feel we should have a generalized code. Everytime we cannot be adding +1,+2 if we need different number of data to be added to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are adding an element so if
Old array has 3 element and you want to add 1 more element so you should make you new array of size 4 which haven't done....
Try String result[] = new String[itemsArray.length + 1]
This might solve your problem

Or

You can simply use ArrayList it will solve all your problems....

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

New array will have one item more than the current one:

```
String[] result = new String[itemsArray.length + 1];
```

Comment: We can't generalize this line of code, what if I need to add two or three extra values? Every time I can't be doing +1,+2,+3 to the array length.

Comment: Well, insertItem just insert one ítem.

Comment: @coderkemp OP says he needs to put one element at given position.

Comment: @Doc I was thinking about adding elements depending on the input, was curious to know how this would work. I came to know linked list could possible be a good option for creating storage as we want.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes

```
private void inserItem(int pos, String value) {
    String[] result = new String[itemsArray.length + 1];//new array with old size+1
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        result[i] = itemsArray[i];

    result[pos] = value;
    for(int i = pos + 1; i < result.length; i++)//change loop termination
        result[i] = itemsArray[i-1];

    itemsArray= result;
}
```

Comment: your comment "increase size" is a little misleading. You are creating a new array of the desired size not increasing the size of the existing array.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] itemsArray = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" };
private String[] inserItem(int pos, String value)
{
        String[] result = new String[itemsArray.Length + 1];

        for (int i = 0, idx = 0; i < itemsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (idx == pos)
            {
                result[idx] = value;
                idx++;
                result[idx] = itemsArray[i];
                idx++;
            }
            else
            {
                result[idx] = itemsArray[i];
                idx++;
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating new array inside your function, create it with (current length + 1). I have edited your code below.

```
private void insertItem(int pos, String value) {
        String[] result = new String[itemsArray.length + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
            result[i] = itemsArray[i];

        result[pos] = value;
        for(int i = pos + 1; i < itemsArray.length + 1; i++)
            result[i] = itemsArray[i-1];

        itemsArray= result;
 }
```

However, please note that what you are doing here is not extending the original array. Instead you are creating a new array from the values of original array and newly added element.